# How to have Neo4j embedded in Java applications + web interface?

Tags: java, neo4j

In Neo4j 1.9.2, I used (code #1) :

```
EmbeddedNeo4j.graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
.newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("path")
.loadPropertiesFromFile( "configpath" )
.newGraphDatabase();
registerShutdownHook( graphDb );
```

to launch Embedded server. Then I used, to get access to the web interface (code #2):

```
WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper srv;
srv = new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper( (GraphDatabaseAPI) graphDb, (ServerConfigurator)config);
srv.start();
```

Since WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper is deprecated in 1.9.5, is there still a way to get access to the web interface (code #1 is ok, but no web interface available)?

Comment: Can you use neo4j as server and write plugin for it?

Comment: You can still use `WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper` for the time being. Time will tell what happens to it.

Answer (score 1):

I only know the non-programmatical-way: Download the Neo4j community edition ([Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/download)), install, start the program, and point it to your db. You can then access the web interface via localhost:7474.